# Массив вместо значения SQL

Tags: java, android

есть запрос к БД

```
Cursor c = db.query(table, null, "external_id = ?", arIdExternal, null, null,null);
```

можно ли подставить массив ? Я хочу найти external_id = 1,2,5 . как можно реализовать?

Comment: [SQL IN Operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй оператор IN, этот оператор позволяет указать список значений.
Пример:

```
String id = TextUtils.join(",", new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 });
db.query(table, null, "external_id IN (" + id + ")", null, null, null, null);
```